# Apache proxy server not passing X-Forwarded-For

Tags: apache-2.4, mod-proxy, x-forwarded-for

I am migrating some sites from one server to another. To avoid any downtime, I am proxying moved sites through the old server while the DNS updates.

On the original (proxy) server, I have the following:

```
    <VirtualHost *:80>
        Servername www.mydomain.com
        DocumentRoot /var/www/mydomain.com

        ProxyPass / http://my-new-server-ip-address/
        ProxyPassReverse / http://my-new-server-ip-address/
        ProxyPreserveHost On
    </VirtualHost>
```

On the new server I am using mod_remoteip (Apache version 2.4.7) and have the following:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
        Servername www.mydomain.com
        DocumentRoot /var/www/mydomain.com

        RemoteIPHeader X-Forwarded-For
        RemoteIPTrustedProxy my-old-server-ip-address

        LogFormat "%a %l %u %t \"%r\" %>s %b \"%{Referer}i\" \"%{User-Agent}i\" (proxy)" proxy

        SetEnvIf X-Forwarded-For "/.*/" forwarded
        # just testing for anything here!!

        CustomLog /var/log/mydomain.com/access.log combined env=!forwarded
        CustomLog /var/log/mydomain.com/access.log proxy env=forwarded
</VirtualHost>
```

What I am trying to achieve is that a different log is used when the request has been proxied as opposed to a direct request from the new server. The "proxy" log never gets executed which makes me think that the "X-Forwarded-For" header is not sent by the original server. The apache docs [here](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_proxy.html#x-headers) state that "X-Forwarded-For" is one of the headers set along.

I know I am missing something obvious but any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Try with `SetEnvIf X-Forwarded-For "^.*\..*\..*\..*" forwarded`

Comment: Thanks @FedericoSierra. I had tried this previously but all I get is the combined log which shows the proxy server's IP address hence me trying to detect anything in the X-Forwarded-For header.